# Getting list of UDP connections via Powershell

Tags: sockets, powershell, tcp

I currently have a server with 5 IPs set up on it.  On this server, I run a game server management system called TCAdmin to assign game servers to IPs and ports.  I am trying to use Powershell to get a list of UDP connections to a specific IP from that pool.  These connections would be the players currently online on that game server. However, when I run netstat to view all connections, there are no TCP or UDP connections that show up.  I just get a list of items that look like this:

```
 UDP    xx.xx.xx.122:138      *:*                                    4
```

I know that there are 20+ players connected to this particular game server, so I'm at a loss on how to script using netstat or another built-in tool to grab the 20+ player connections.

Any help or pointers is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Found this
https://learn-powershell.net/2011/02/21/querying-udp-ports-with-powershell/

```
 function Get-NetworkStatistics 
    { 
        $properties = ‘Protocol’,’LocalAddress’,’LocalPort’ 
        $properties += ‘RemoteAddress’,’RemotePort’,’State’,’ProcessName’,’PID’

        netstat -ano | Select-String -Pattern ‘\s+(TCP|UDP)’ | ForEach-Object {

            $item = $_.line.split(” “,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

            if($item[1] -notmatch ‘^\[::’) 
            {            
                if (($la = $item[1] -as [ipaddress]).AddressFamily -eq ‘InterNetworkV6’) 
                { 
                   $localAddress = $la.IPAddressToString 
                   $localPort = $item[1].split(‘\]:’)[-1] 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $localAddress = $item[1].split(‘:’)[0] 
                    $localPort = $item[1].split(‘:’)[-1] 
                } 

                if (($ra = $item[2] -as [ipaddress]).AddressFamily -eq ‘InterNetworkV6’) 
                { 
                   $remoteAddress = $ra.IPAddressToString 
                   $remotePort = $item[2].split(‘\]:’)[-1] 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                   $remoteAddress = $item[2].split(‘:’)[0] 
                   $remotePort = $item[2].split(‘:’)[-1] 
                } 

                New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
                    PID = $item[-1] 
                    ProcessName = (Get-Process -Id $item[-1] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Name 
                    Protocol = $item[0] 
                    LocalAddress = $localAddress 
                    LocalPort = $localPort 
                    RemoteAddress =$remoteAddress 
                    RemotePort = $remotePort 
                    State = if($item[0] -eq ‘tcp’) {$item[3]} else {$null} 
                } | Select-Object -Property $properties 
            } 
        } 
    }

    Get-NetworkStatistics | Format-Table
```